# Displaying validation messages for an input form

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, flask

I'm trying to capture all input fields in a form (i.e. sign_up.html)  & validating them - if one of them is null or empty then it should show a validation message. I've done it but I'm looking for an elegant way to do it.

### sign_up.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block main %}
<form action="/sign_up.html" method="POST" autocomplete="off" name="sign_up">

    <h2>Sign Up</h2>

    <label for="username">User name:
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="required" maxlength="20">
    </label>
    <br>

    <sup>* Password must be 8-12 Digit ,Numbers & letters & punctuations @, !, $, ETC..</sup>
    <label for="password">Password:
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" required="required" minlength="8" maxlength="12">
    </label>

    <label for="check">Check Password:
        <input type="password" placeholder="Check Password" name="check" required="required" minlength="8" maxlength="12">
    </label>
    <br>

    <label for="security_question">Security question :
        <select name="security_question">
            <option value="where were you born?" name="q1" >where were you born?</option>
            <option value="what is your favorite nickname?" name="q2" >what is your favorite nickname?</option>
            <option value="what is the name of your first pet?" name="q3" >what is the name of your first pet?</option>
            <option value="what is the name of your first best friend?" name="q4" >what is the name of your first best friend?</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <label for="answer">Security answer:
        <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" name="answer" required="required">
    </label>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

this is my spaghetti validation python code:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, Request, request, session
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableOrderedMultiDict
from werkzeug.utils import HTMLBuilder

#Something in between

class OrderedRequest(Request):
    parameter_storage_class = ImmutableOrderedMultiDict

app = Flask(__name__)

app.request_class = OrderedRequest

#Something in between

@app.route("/sign_up.html",  methods=["GET", "POST"])
def sign_up():

if request.method == "POST":

        #assigning returning page
        page = "sign_up.html"

        #Null fields checking
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return render_template("errors/general_error.html", error = "Username field is Empty", page = page)

        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return render_template("errors/general_error.html", error = "Password field is Empty", page = page)

        elif not request.form.get("check"):
            return render_template("errors/general_error.html", error = "Check Password field is Empty", page = page)

        elif not request.form.get("answer"):
            return render_template("errors/general_error.html", error = "answer field is Empty", page = page)

#something at the end
```

this will return a page with the validation error massage.

I need to loop through an element gives me names of all the inputs inside the form & I'll return the error massage due to it..

& code will be like:

```
for i in needed_element:
    if not i:
        return render_template("errors/general_error.html", error = f"{i} field is Empty", page = page)
```

or something similar or any more elegant way because I'm repeating this step many times in the project :'D

Answer (score 2):

### Readability

Before addressing the main concern, readability should be addressed.

Many python developers adhere to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for consistent code style.

This code does not adhere to a few aspects:

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters. 
> For flowing long blocks of text with fewer structural restrictions (docstrings or comments), the line length should be limited to 72 characters.

> Don't use spaces around the = sign when used to indicate a keyword argument, or when used to indicate a default value for an unannotated function parameter:

### Repeated code

As you already identified, the code to check for missing fields in order to display validation prior errors is quite redundant. This goes against the [***D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself* principle](http://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/) .

One option is to abstract out the fields to check into a dictionary:

```
field_mapping = {'username': 'Username', 'password': 'Password',
                 'check': 'Check Password', 'answer': 'Answer'}
```

Then the `items()` method can be used to [iterate through the keys and values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques), unpacked to a tuple:

```
for field, label in field_mapping.items():
    if not request.form.get(field):
        return render_template("errors/general_error.html",
                               error=f"{label} field is Empty", page=page)
```

Comment: many thanks for Readability instruction's.
I found that too I can easily do
```
for i in request.form:
            if not request.form.get(i):
                return render_template("errors/general_error.html", error = i + " field is Empty", page=page)
```

Comment: Ah I had considered mentioning that but figured it wouldn't allow customizing the label - e.g. `check` -> `Check Password`

Comment: that's a nice concentration, I find that too so I changed the input names to be `check -> check_password` then applying `"check_password".replace("_"," ").capitalize()` when returning values to jinja.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can iterate through form inputs by doing this..

```
for i in request.form:
            if not request.form.get(i):
                return render_template("errors/general_error.html", error = i + " field is Empty", page=page)
```

as request.form will give you a list contains all names of inputs in form.

Note: it excludes `<input type="submit" value="Sign Up">` by default, because this input have no name.